# how to show specific widget when data coming from streamBuilder is empty []?

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

im getting a list of objects from my cloud firestore database but even when my collection is empty or not even exist my streamBuilder keep going inside (snapshot.hasData == true)

```
StreamBuilder<List<Patient>>(
        stream: FirebaseApi().getAllPatients,
        builder: (context, snapshot) {
          if (snapshot.hasData == true) {
            var data = snapshot.data;
            return Column(
              children: [
                buildSearch(),
                query == ''
                    ? buildAllPatients(data)
                    : filteredPatientsNum(data: data).length != 0
                        ? buildFilteredPatients(data)
                        : Center(
                            child: Text('No Patients Found'),
                          ),
              ],
            );
          } else if (snapshot.hasData == false) {
            return Center(child: Text('No Patients'));
          }
          return Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
        },
      ),
```

[the result on the emulator here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7Ejdy.png)

what i want to do is to enter the case (snapshot.hasdata == false) and show the text ('no patients') on the screen when my collection has no documents or not existed

here is the stream code

```
  Stream<List<Patient>> get getAllPatients {
    return FirebaseFirestore.instance
        .collection('Patients')
        .snapshots()
        .map(patientsListFromQuerySnapShot);
  }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, that is how it works. `snapshot.hasData` will be true if the request succeeds.

If you want to know if it is empty or not, use this:

```
if (snapshot.data.isNotEmpty) {
  // should be snapshot.data.docs.isNotEmpty above, but I used this because 
  // you've already mapped it
  // is not empty
  return Column(
    // ...
  );
} else {
  // is empty
  return Center(child: Text('No Patients'));
}
```

If it was me, this is how I would write it:

```
StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
  stream: FirebaseFirestore.instance
        .collection('Patients')
        .snapshots(),
        // notice I did not map it here as you did
        // above is your getAllPatientsStream
  builder: (BuildContext context,
      AsyncSnapshot<QuerySnapshot> snapshot) {
    if (snapshot.hasError) return Center(child: Text('An error occured'));;
    if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting)
      return Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
    if (snapshot.hasData && snapshot.data.docs.isEmpty)
      return Center(child: Text('No Patients'));

    List data = snapshot.data.docs.map((e) => e.data()).toList();
    // I mapped here and mine above contains snapshot.data.docs
    return Column(
      // ...
    );
  },
)
```

Comment: thanks for your help :) i got the result i need , but is there a big different between my way and yours ? like better performance or anything else ?

Comment: None at all. So glad I could help.